# Add class to header if page is index.php using jQuery

Tags: jquery, addclass

Using jQuery, I want to add a class to `<header>` tag only if on index.php

Pseudo code:

```
var page_name = get current page name
if
   $page_name == 'index.php' 
then
   add 'is_index' class to <header>
else 
   do nothing
```

I am wanting to style the header differently on the index page only, therefore am trying to insert a selector to grab onto with CSS.  I can achieve in PHP, but I can't find what jQuery function to use. I need to use jQuery as `<header>` may already have a class and I do not believe PHP can add to an element that already has a class (but perhaps I am wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple

```
$('header').toggleClass('is_index', /\/index.php$/.test(location.pathname))
```

**Note:** This will toggle the class on *all* `<header>` elements if you have more than one.

The docs for `toggleClass()` are here ~ http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state

---

Also, there should be no problem doing this in PHP

```
<?php $isIndex = basename(__FILE__) == 'index.php';
    // or however you determine you're on index.php
?>
<header class="whatever <?= $isIndex ? 'is_index' : '' ?>">
```